# What is an "incongruent" solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, "Solve the congruence (if possible), listing all the incongruent solutions:"

$$561x\equiv 3575\mod{1562}$$

I found $x\equiv 37+142t,\ 0\leq t\leq 10,\ t\in\mathbb{Z}$... There are 11 "incongruent solutions" because $(561,1562)=11$ and $11\mid 3575$... but what does "incongruent" mean?

Comment: congruent modulo $m$ : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why is it not called "congruence" then, not "incongruence"?

Comment: congruent values are not considered distinct,  right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Incongruent (in this case) means distinct modulo $1562$. For example, $1$ and $1561$ are incongruent modulo $1562$, but $1$ and $1563$ are not (rather, they are *congruent* modulo $1562$).

Comment: Does this mean that there are 11 different equivalence classes?

Comment: Yes, indeed. There are eleven different equivalence classes of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

if we consider
$ x= 37,1599,3161....... $
then all are solution for x and that all are congruent each other because they are all 37 more than a multiple of 1562. so they all belongs to a same congruence class usually denoted by [37]

also satisfying the congruence are 
$ x=179, 1741, 3303 $
but these solutions,, belongs to the same congruence class, usually denoted by [179] are not congruent to any solution in class [37] mod 1562.

similar to the other 9 solutions

so x= 37, 179, ... are incongruence solutions because they belong to different congruence classes.